# Button is not working after first successful ajax data laod

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
var Update = {
     init: function(){
       $('.find').on('click', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var
              $this = $(this),
              $form = $('#searchForm');
              BLC.ajax({
               url: "/emp/find",
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: data
              },function(data){                                
                  $('#findEmployees').html(data);
              });
          });
     }
 };
```

```html
<div id="findEmployees">


 <blc:form method="POST" th:action="@{/emp/find" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{employee.id}" name="id" id="id" />
  <button id="find" name="find" class="find" type="button"
   th:text="Find"></button>

 </blc:form>

 <blc:form class="detailform" name="detailform"
  th:action="@{/emp/deatils}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" th:id="id" th:name="id" th:value="*{id}" />

  <a href="#" class="empLink">
   <h4 th:text="*{id}"></h4>

  </a>
 </blc:form>


</div>
```

Comment: What button doesnt work?

Comment: find button is not responding after first ajax call its not even going int to the java script method "update". To be clear I want to load the employee information based on emp id. Somehow it works only first time.

Comment: That code is pretty messy, try to follow some coding conventions. The var statement is missing a coma after $from = ... . It's really hard to edit your question to follow coding conventions without changing how the code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are replacing the content in the div with the new content from the Ajax call, you need to reference the document and delegate the event handler to the newly added code.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.find', function(e){....
```